# Cannot connect to Raspbian Jessie via VNC Viewer

Tags: pi-2, vnc

I am unable to connect to my Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian Jessie via the built-in VNC Server. I got it working at home but now that I am on my university's network I am not sure what is wrong..

I am able to SSH into it perfectly via terminal on my Mac but when I try to connect to it using VNC Viewer I get 'Timed out waiting for a response from the computer'

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The standard VNC ports may be blocked on the campus network.

Comment: would there be a way for me to unblock them?

Comment: Are you using the correct vnc viewer?

Comment: @ElefantPhace yes I'm 100% sure I'm using the correct vnc viewer, it worked for me at home.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a while ago, and I couldn't figure it out. I ended up reinstalling the raspbian os and starting up VNC from scratch and it worked again. Not promising it will work for you but it's worth trying. And as suggested earlier your school might be blocking the VNC ports, although I doubt a school would go to that much trouble.